# Is there a way to control cryptomatte colors? for object colors for instance masking out of the box in blender

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, masking, instances, cryptomatte

Is there a way to know each color of each object before it will be rendered? Or a way to setup colors for each object. In other words I need to setup a preseted color for each object on the scene.

Simple scripting with changing materials won't work.

https://gyazo.com/b803e1d0de54654e5d11ce42f0539c6f
https://gyazo.com/351b44d53b4cef562ad2c2bd6ff51e76